# Placing the equation number in the left-hand margin

Tags: formatting, equations, cross-referencing, numbering, margins

I use

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{{\hspace*{-3.05cm}\thesection.\arabic{equation}}}
```

to move my equation numbers into the margins (corporate design), it looks like this:

[image: Equation number in margin]

The problem is that apparently this command is also used to make references in the text, so when doing `(\ref{equation:label})` I get this:

[image: Bad reference]

As you can see, everything behind the `(` gets pulled to the left by 3.05cm, as defined above. Is there any way to get the references and equation environment to use different commands for the equation numbers so I can define them the way I need them?

### Edit

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[leqno,11pt,parskip,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=5.6cm,right=2.2cm,top=5.5cm,bottom=3.55cm,headsep=1.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}

% remove brackets from equation numbers
\newtagform{brackets}{}{}
\usetagform{brackets}

% Equation numbers
\renewcommand{\theequation}{{\fontsize{8bp}{8bp}\selectfont\hspace*{-3.05cm}\thesection.\arabic{equation}}}

\begin{document}
\section{TestSection}
\begin{equation}
a = b+c
\label{test}
\end{equation}

This is a reference (\ref{test})

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using `mathtools` you alredy have all the tools(!) you need. You even invoked the right macro, `\newtagform` -- in which you can specify how your tags should be formatted:

```
\newtagform{brackets}{\hspace*{-3.05cm}\fontsize{8bp}{8bp}\selectfont}{}
```

Doing so, you need to take care `\eqref` (as it uses `\tagform@` which like in the solution of @DavidCarlisle gets redefined; only with less effort ;)

You can use the patch of Davids solution to fix this or define a custom command:

```
\newcommand{\myeqref}[1]{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}
```

which omits `\tagform@`. Alternatively you could also `\renewcommand\eqref` itself to this form (shouldn't be harmfull, but I can't say this for sure now).

[image: output_complete-code]

#### Complete code

```
\documentclass[leqno,11pt,parskip,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=5.6cm,right=2.2cm,top=5.5cm,bottom=3.55cm,headsep=1.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
  \newtagform{brackets}{\hspace*{-3.05cm}\fontsize{8bp}{8bp}\selectfont}{}
  \usetagform{brackets}
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\usepackage[hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
  \counterwithin*{equation}{section}

\newcommand{\myeqref}[1]{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}% or
%\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}

%for testing purposes
\DeclareMathOperator{\dop}{d}
\DeclareMathOperator{\spot}{spot}
\DeclareMathOperator{\low}{lower}

\setcounter{section}{6}

\begin{document}
\section{Test section}
\lipsum[1]    
\begin{equation}\label{test}
\dop^2_p = 2\cdot\dop^2_{\spot}\cdot\bigg(\frac{\Phi}{\Phi_{\low}}\bigg)
\end{equation}    
This is a reference \myeqref{test}. \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that `\newtagform` could do this. Since I only use `\ref`, this is the most elegant solution for me.

Answer (score 7):

Redefinining `\theequation` in that way is wrong. The LaTeX `\thezzzz` macros are supposed to be safe to *expand* in tables of contents and other expansion contexts to the formatting of *just* the number.

The code to position the number should be elsewhere. If you are using `amsmath` then the macro to redefine is `\maketag@@@`

which has default definition

```
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont#1}}
```

with the MWE now supplied:

```
\documentclass[leqno,11pt,parskip,oneside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=5.6cm,right=2.2cm,top=5.5cm,bottom=3.55cm,headsep=1.9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithin*{equation}{section}

% remove brackets from equation numbers
\newtagform{brackets}{}{}
\usetagform{brackets}

% Equation numbers
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

\makeatletter
\let\oldmaketag@@@\maketag@@@
\def\oldtagform@#1{\oldmaketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\oldtagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\hskip1sp\m@th\llap{%
\fontsize{8bp}{8bp}\normalfont\normalcolor
\normalfont#1\hspace{3.05cm}%
}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{TestSection}
\begin{equation}
a = b+c
\label{test}
\end{equation}

This is a reference (\ref{test})


This is a reference \eqref{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to insert own adjustments into that command? I tired `\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\hspace*{-3.05cm}#1}}` but nothing happens, the equation number is not moved in any way.

Comment: @user3696412 see update, now you have supplied a MWE:-)

Comment: Interestingly, the position of the cross-reference is correct if it's generated via `\ref`, but it's not if generated via `\eqref`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works now like a charme. However, I will use Ruben solution since I already have that  `\newtagform` call in there and only need to add in that line.